# Assembler Not Working Wrong Result

Tags: assembly

i'm new to assembler and i'm not really sure what's wrong with this little program i've made.All it does is a+b*c. The program works with tasm,tlink and everything. It even shows me to give values to a,b,c but the result is like 50 lines of symbols...i dont get it.

```
dosseg              
.model small            
.stack          
.data               
mesaj_a  db 13,10,' Introduceti numarul a:$'    
mesaj_b  db 13,10,' Introduceti numarul b:$'   
mesaj_c  db 13,10,' Introduceti numarul c:$'   
afis_rez  db 13,10,' Rezultat:$'   
.code                   
pstart:
    mov ax,@data        
    mov ds,ax  
;--------------        
    mov dx, offset mesaj_a     
    mov ah,09          
    int 21h        
    mov ah, 0ah        
    int 21h        
    mov  bx,ax         
;----------------
    mov dx, offset mesaj_b    
    mov ah,09         
    int 21h        
    mov ah, 0ah        
    int 21h        
    mov  cx,ax      

;----------------
    mov dx, offset mesaj_c     
    mov ah,09            
    int 21h          
    mov ah, 0ah        
    int 21h        
;---------------
    mul cx               
    add  ax,bx         
    mov  bx,ax    

;---------------
    mov dx, offset afis_rez   
    mov ah,09             
    int 21h          
    mov dx,bx         
    int 21h       
;---------------
    mov ax, 4ch        
    int 21h  
end  pstart
```

Comment: You can't print a number simply by setting `dx` to have the value to print. You need to convert it to a string. `dx` contains the *offset* of the message to print, like `mov dx, offset afis_rez`. As such, the pair `mov dx,bx` and `int 21h` near the bottom will print whatever characters are in memory at the offset you've calculated `bx` to be.

Comment: And the same is true for **reading** the number - see http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a what function `0ah` expects as input and delivers as output. You need to convert the string returned in the buffer to a number after reading it.

Comment: You mean i should change every 0ah into 01?What about mov dx,bx...what should i write instead of dx?

Answer (score 0):

```
mov dx,bx         
int 21h
```

There's no DOS interrupt for printing numbers. You'll have to convert the numerical value to a string yourself and then print the string using `INT 21H / AH=9`.

---

Also, this line:

```
mov ax, 4ch
```

should be:

```
mov ax,4c00h
```

(the function number needs to go into `AH`, which is the upper half of `AX`)